# "Connect" Arraylist to Integerlist

Tags: android, arrays

I have a litle problem dealing with arrays.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images_primes);

    List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    Collections.shuffle(indexes);

    Log.d("MYAPP", "value: " + indexes);

    int randomPrimeNumber = (int) (indexes());

    // setImageResource to the random chosenImageNumber
    imageViewMeasurement.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(randomPrimeNumber, R.color.colorGreyMeasuerementScreen));
}
```

What does it do?

1. Get the array of images from a resource file (working) -> (typedArray images).
2. List indexes = List that is as long as "images" -> shuffles list, works! -> D/MYAPP: value: [4, 9, 10, 8, 3, 1, 7, 2, 5, 6]

3/4. Would be: go through the shuffled list of "indexes", call the numbers from there on the array of "images", setImageresource.

Question:
Concerning point 2: can I create the List indexes dependend on images.length of the "images"-array?

Concerning point 3-4: I can't get the two arrays (images / shuffled indexes) together. It shows errors about unable to cast integer to int, when I try to  set

```
int randomPrimeNumber = (int) (indexes);
```

for example.

Is there a possibility to "mix" the two arrays?

Best and thanks,
tigercode

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to create the `indexes` list, if you want to generate a random number smaller than the length of the `images` array, just use `Random`:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(images.length());
```

And yes, there's a `length()` method in `TypedArray` class.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I need to go through the list and call randomly EVERY item from the list, not picking out ramdomly an item from the list.
<pre><code>
First code was:                  
    TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images_primes);
    int chosenImageNumber = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());
</code></pre>

but this produces for example. 1,3,3,4,4,6,7,8,9,10 from 10 trials, not every item ;-)